# When I run a macro it blanks the data in the fields

Tags: excel, vba

Why are all fields blank after this macro is executed?  When I run this macro it blanks all of the data in the fields but formats the sheet correctly.  It happens between the .apply and End with, just before the active window screens.  I did not write this macro, any help would be appreciated.

I have used the step into feature to find where this unwanted behavior happens.

```
    Columns("T:AD").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("I:S").Select
    Range("S1").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("A1:S1000").Select
    Range("D1").Activate
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Columns("G:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("I:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Cells.Select
    Range("D1").Activate
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Range("D1").Activate
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Cells.Select
    Range("D1").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("P2:P1000") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:AD1000")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-33
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 11
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 12
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 13
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 14
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 15
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 16
    Range("A28").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-75
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

Comment: search for the word delete (it's there twice) start from there

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this:

```
Columns("I:S").Select
```

You are selecting all columns entirely, and then afterwards (as correctly mentioned by Tin Bum) you are deleting everything left of those columns.

At the end, you're also deleting the first two rows entirely, but I believe that's not a big problem.